# How to call ucwords in twig?

Tags: twig

**EDIT: Dec 3 2016**

- Want to learn how to add custom extensions(filters) to twig? see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31145730/2401804) by [lxg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3908235/lxg)
- Do you just need to find the twig equivalent for ucwords? see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31182983/2401804) by [Javier Eguiluz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2804294/javier-eguiluz)

I found several posts on calling php functions from twig, that show it should be supported, however it doesn't seem to work.

`{{ ucwords( item|replace({'_':' '}) ) }}`

results in :l

> **Slim Application Error**
>
> The application could not run because of the following error:
>
> **Details**
>
> **Type:** Twig_Error_Syntax Message: The function "ucwords" does not exist
>   in "home.twig" at line 101
>
> **File:**
>   /usr/share/dev89/html/vhosts/local/libs/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/ExpressionParser.php
>   Line: 572

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update**: Twig 2.x comes with the [`capitalize`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/capitalize.html) filter which does exactly that.

---

It is not true that all PHP functions are available in Twig. Only a *few* Twig [filters](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/index.html) and [functions](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/index.html) go by the same names as their equivalents in PHP.

But you can easily create your own [Twig extension](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#creating-an-extension) for `ucwords` – filter as well as function:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\TestBundle\Twig;

class UcWordsExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return [
            new \Twig_SimpleFunction('ucwords', 'ucwords')
        ];
    }

    public function getFilters()
    {
        return [
            new \Twig_SimpleFilter('ucwords', 'ucwords')
        ];
    }
    
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'ext.ucwords';
    }

}
```

The first parameter of `Twig_SimpleFunction`/`Twig_SimpleFilter` is the name of the function/filter in Twig. The second parameter is a PHP callable. As the `ucfirst` function already exists, it is sufficient to pass its name as a string.

Test in Twig:

```
{{ "test foobar"|ucwords }} {# filter #} <br>
{{ ucwords("test foobar") }} {# function #}
```

Returns:

```
Test Foobar
Test Foobar
```

Answer (score 31):

As @lxg said, it's not possible to call all PHP functions from Twig templates ... unless you want to do that and define your own filters/functions. Instead of a drawback, this is a good thing to "force" you to create good templates that don't contain too much logic.

Anyway, in this particular case, Twig already contains a filter called [title](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/title.html) which applies the "title case", which is equivalent to the `ucwords()` PHP function:

```
{{ item|replace({'_':' '})|title }}
```

Comment: No it isn't a good feature. by doing so, it forces double iteration of arrays where you need to capitalize things, because you will have to iterate once in model then twig will need to iterate again for generating the view. doesn't make any sense at all.

Comment: It's clear that you don't agree with us :) What I tried to say is this: in the past, it was normal to put PHP code, database queries and HTML in a single template. Nowadays, the recommendation is to put PHP code in `src/` and include as little code as possible in the templates. That's why Twig filters and functions provide just the minimum features to be useful for tweaking template contents, but not enough features to include a lot of code and make them a mess.

Comment: that sounds like an elitist thing to say. One can create nice templates without making them messy. Availability of Functions don't enable bad programming, bad programming enables bad programming.

Comment: To clarify the discussion, a best practice within the community is to perform "business logic" outside of views, and supply the necessary object models and data to the view using `MVC` design pattern.  Things like `ucwords` are fine inside of views, but would be better handled by a model. Like `item::getTitle()` then using `{{ item.title }}` in your twig template. This way if you change how `item::getTitle()` functions in the model, it is applied to all views. Significantly reducing code management and refactoring, since the model handles the heavy lifting rather than the templates.

Answer (score 12):

Why not use `title` filter?
I was looking for a filter that will work as like `ucwords()` php function and I found this `title` filter in [Twig Documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/title.html).

Usage example;

```
{{ 'i am raziul islam'|title }}
```

> Outputs: I Am Raziul Islam

Answer (score 2):

You can use the capitalize [twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/capitalize.html) filter:

```
{{ item | capitalize }}
```

Comment: Capitalize only "capitalize" the first letter of the sentence, not all the words.

Comment: Capitalize is similar to `ucfirst` of php but he asked for ucwords